# How to add new locale?

Tags: locale, upload, contributing

How to add completely new locale which doesn't exist yet. I can create a locale file. But it's possible to upload it (git) for have it in future releases out of the box??

Answer (score 1):

The locales in Ubuntu are provided by glibc, so you'd propose the new locale to be included there. Example bug report:

https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=23208